# Store an API_KEY in an env var and use in a playlist URL

Tags: bash, environment-variables, global-variables, audio-streaming, playlist

I use a streaming service (di.fm) that has many channels. Each channel has a playlist I stream from the CLI (using mpv). Each URL in each playlist stores the API KEY.

I want to store the API KEY outside of the individual playlists, so for example, if I change the API KEY, I don't have to change every playlist.

I'm on a Mac.

1) What is the best (safest) place to declare `export DI_KEY=""`? In .bashrc was my first thought, except I back it up to github. Any other better place to declare the env var that will be created each time I enter bash?

2) In the playlist file, how do I use the `$DI_KEY` in the URL?

```
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=1
File1=http://prem4.di.fm:80/00sclubhits?$DI_KEY
Title1=DI.FM - 00s Club Hits
Length1=0
Version=2
```

Just referencing it directly doesn't work.

[image]

I'm sure this may be answered elsewhere, but in all my searching I couldn't find any helpful answers, particularly to questions 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding setting env variables outside of `.bashrc`, you could create a separate file to define sensitive variables and source this from within your `.bashrc`.

For example, create a file `~.my-private-variables`, add the filename to your `.gitignore` and add the line `export DI_KEY="12345"` to this file. Then add the following block in `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.my-private-variables ]; then                                                                               
  . ~/.my-private-variables                                                                                         
fi
```

Regarding the playlist file, bash is not running the file, so the environment variable is not expanded.

You could dynamically generate the playlist when bash starts, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=playlist-1.pls
baseurl=http://prem4.di.fm:80

cat << EOF > $filename
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=1
File1=${baseurl}/00sclubhits?${DI_KEY}
Title1=DI.FM - 00s Club Hits
Length1=0
Version=2
EOF
```

This will expand the variable and write it to the file, in this case `playlist-1.pls` in the current working directory. You might add an absolute path to the filename variable that references your playlists directory.

To run this, you could create a script called `playlist-generator` and source this in `.bashrc` as described above. You could add as many playlists as you like here.

Comment: Excellent ideas and explanations... I knew there was a way to do that with the .bashrc, I just couldn't find the best way. Thanks for the quick lesson!

Comment: @Neal glad it helped!